# Replace values for each ID and each month in IBM DB2 SQL?

Tags: sql, db2

I have about several milion record table in IBM DB2 with 4 columns: yeas, month, personal_number (2 milion), personal_id. The key is that I want to get same table from this one, but I want to fill  in personal_id column value from last month (in all previous months). Point is to get 1-1: 1 personal_id relate to 1 personal_number.

Here is my code, but error is that now I have 4 in all monhts (and I need 1,2,3,4 for months)

```
    With CTE As
(
    SELECT  
            a.YEAR,
            a.MONTH, 
            a.PERSONAL_NUMBER, 
            a.PERSONAL_ID, 
            
            Row_Number() Over (Partition By a.YEAR, a.PERSONAL_NUMBER
                                     Order By a.MONTH DESC) Rn
    FROM
    DWH.PA A
    )
SELECT 
D.YEAR, D.MONTH, D.PERSONAL_NUMBER, D.PERSONAL_ID
FROM CTE D
RIGHT JOIN
(
SELECT
YEAR,
MONTH,
PERSONAL_NUMBER
FROM
DWH.PA
) B
ON (D.PERSONAL_NUMBER = B.PERSONAL_NUMBER)
WHERE D.Rn = 1 
;
```

Here is the start table:

| YEAR | MONTH | PERSONAL_NUMBER | PERSONAL_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 1 | AA | 8 |
| 2020 | 2 | AA | 5 |
| 2020 | 3 | AA | 5 |
| 2020 | 4 | AA | 1 |
| 2020 | 1 | BB | 2 |
| 2020 | 2 | BB | 2 |
| 2020 | 3 | BB | 3 |
| 2020 | 4 | BB | 3 |

Here is the result (it is not very well result):

| YEAR | MONTH | PERSONAL_NUMBER | PERSONAL_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 4 | AA | 1 |
| 2020 | 4 | AA | 1 |
| 2020 | 4 | AA | 1 |
| 2020 | 4 | AA | 1 |
| 2020 | 4 | BB | 3 |
| 2020 | 4 | BB | 3 |
| 2020 | 4 | BB | 3 |
| 2020 | 4 | BB | 3 |

Here is the what I need:

| YEAR | MONTH | PERSONAL_NUMBER | PERSONAL_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 1 | AA | 1 |
| 2020 | 2 | AA | 1 |
| 2020 | 3 | AA | 1 |
| 2020 | 4 | AA | 1 |
| 2020 | 1 | BB | 3 |
| 2020 | 2 | BB | 3 |
| 2020 | 3 | BB | 3 |
| 2020 | 4 | BB | 3 |

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH T (YEAR, MONTH, PERSONAL_NUMBER, PERSONAL_ID) AS
(
VALUES
  (2020, 1, 'AA', 8)
, (2020, 2, 'AA', 5)
, (2020, 3, 'AA', 5)
, (2020, 4, 'AA', 1)
, (2020, 1, 'BB', 2)
, (2020, 2, 'BB', 2)
, (2020, 3, 'BB', 3)
, (2020, 4, 'BB', 3)
)
SELECT 
  T.*
, FIRST_VALUE(PERSONAL_ID) OVER 
  (PARTITION BY YEAR, PERSONAL_NUMBER ORDER BY MONTH DESC) PERSONAL_ID_NEW
FROM T;
```

The result is:

```
|YEAR|MONTH|PERSONAL_NUMBER|PERSONAL_ID|PERSONAL_ID_NEW|
|----|-----|---------------|-----------|---------------|
|2020|4    |AA             |1          |1              |
|2020|3    |AA             |5          |1              |
|2020|2    |AA             |5          |1              |
|2020|1    |AA             |8          |1              |
|2020|4    |BB             |3          |3              |
|2020|3    |BB             |3          |3              |
|2020|2    |BB             |2          |3              |
|2020|1    |BB             |2          |3              |
```

Comment: Thank you @Mark Barinstein. This is the solution! Thank you again. I just rearrange part: PARTITION BY PERSONAL_NUMBER ORDER BY YEAR,  MONTH DESC) PERSONAL_ID_NEW
FROM T since I would have 2021 in one moment also

Comment: I tried to vote as 1, but I think I have no rights for it? Srry, I am new here, if I can vote somehow for this answer pls write me.

Comment: If your goal is to get `PERSONAL_ID` for the last month, then use `DESC` ordering for both `ORDER BY` columns: `PARTITION BY PERSONAL_NUMBER ORDER BY YEAR DESC, MONTH DESC)`.

Comment: Thank you Mark. That is it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood what you wanted correctly, but try this:

```
SELECT
  YEAR,
  MONTH,
  PERSONAL_NUMBER,
  (
    SELECT PERSONAL_ID
    FROM DWH.PA AS B 
    WHERE A.YEAR = B.YEAR
    AND A.PERSONAL_NUMBER = B.PERSONAL_NUMBER
    ORDER BY MONTH DESC
    FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
   ) AS PERSONAL_ID
 FROM DWH.PA AS A
```

Comment: Thank you @Turophile but it is not ok, since your solution have multiple PERSONAL_ID and I need just one from last month, to fill in all previous monts.